# reactjs lifecycle is there a visual flowchart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm running into alot of issues with reactjs mainly because I'm not exactly sure of the component lifecycle and at *precisely* what point things like setState do things.

I am aware there is a page titled "Component Lifecycle" but I need a much more detailed visual diagram showing how reactjs lifecycle works, in particular showing where and when setState does things.

Is there such a diagram?

Comment: found a tutorial here http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2014/09/13/execution-sequence-of-a-react-components-lifecycle-methods/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be useful to you? It shows where `setState()` can be called and where it cannot. It also shows what lifecycle methods receive the new state.

[image: react lifecycle]

Comment: This immediately solved the problem I was having.  It should be part of the reactjs documentation.